# Setting up staging environment for heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am coming in late to add some functionality to an already existing app hosted on heroku. The original builder has given me access and I 'heroku git:clone -a app-name' to my local computer.

I've found some conflicting instructions on how to set up a staging environment for this site. I don't want to push to the original site but want a way to try out functionality.

If anyone has had experience with staging and heroku, I'd appreciate any clarification.

Comment: http://www.mattboldt.com/heroku-staging-production-environments/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a `staging.rb` file in `config/environments`. You can copy `development.rb` or `production.rb` and adjust whatever values you need.

Heroku will handle configuring the database configuration and such. You can clone an app in Heroku or just create a new one, then set it's `RAILS_ENV` and `RACK_ENV` environment variables to `staging`, and push to it.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer: [Heroku - Managing Multiple Environments for an App](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)

You Need to create a second Heroku application that hosts your staging application.

Follow the instructions provided in the link for working with multiple environment in heroku.